# Not getting Field "Assigned To" and "Last update date of Workitem" from the WorkItemCollection

Tags: c#, tfs

I am getting the workitemcollection by using below code

```
public WorkItemCollection QueryWorkItems(string serverName, string projectName, string extendedWIQLQuery)
{
    var server = new Uri(serverName);
    var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(server);
    WorkItemStore workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)tfs.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
    Project p = workItemStore.Projects[projectName];
    string wiqlQuery = "Select * from WorkItem where [System.TeamProject] = '" + projectName + "'";
    wiqlQuery += extendedWIQLQuery;
    WorkItemCollection witCollection = workItemStore.Query(wiqlQuery);
    return witCollection;
}
```

I am iterating this collection by foreach statement as below

```
 foreach (WorkItem wi in res)
        {
           .................
        }
```

I am getting some fields of the TFSItem.

Specially I need Fields "Assigned To" , "Last update date of Workitem" , Priority etc.

Is it possible to get most of the fields (like Priority,IssueType,HowFound etc ) of TFS by using TFS API into any collection or Class ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got all the fields in TFS work item including "assigned to" from the Field Collection. If you iterate through the filed collection you can get all the values of TFS fields.

Answer (score 6):

You do not need to itterate through the Fields collection to get a field value.

```
foreach (WorkItem wi in res)
{
    var assignedTo = wi["Assigned To"];

    //wi["FieldName"]

    wi["Assigned To"] = "Johnny Dev"'


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here what I have end up with.
Filter for a specific TFS project, Iteration, and User

```
    sQuery.AppendLine("SELECT * ")
    sQuery.AppendLine(" FROM WorkItems ")
    sQuery.AppendLine(" WHERE ")
    sQuery.AppendLine("     [Team Project] = '" & pProject.Name & "' ")
    sQuery.AppendLine("     AND [Iteration Path] = '" & currentSprint.IterationPath & "' ")
    sQuery.AppendLine("     AND [Assigned To] = '[Replace with UserName]'")

    Dim result = pProject.Store.Query(sQuery.ToString)
```

Maybe it could help someone!